# Is there any way to get selected chart (selected series, selected point) in Office.JS

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have a lot of VBA/VSTO excel addins based on ability to define user's selected chartobjects, such as chart, series and point. Is there analog of function getSelectedRange but for chartobject in Office JS API. Thanks

Comment: There's an event.  Maybe you can set a global variable that contains the selected chart (or something) when that event is fired.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chart?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-chart-onactivated-member

Answer (score 1):

We have a getActiveChart() JS API. Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-workbook-getactivechart-member(1)). Hope it works for you.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's what I need